# Chrome browser initiated through ChromeDriver gets detected

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium chromedriver in python for the website www.mouser.co.uk. However, it is detected as bot from the first shot .

[image]

Does any one has an explanation for this ?. hereafter the code i am using :

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
browser.get('https://www.mouser.co.uk')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Comment: possible duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tried to access the url `https://www.mouser.co.uk/` with certain *chrome.options* but did get detected and was redirected to **Pardon Our Interruption** page.

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.mouser.co.uk")
  myElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='1_lnkLeftFlag']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", myElement)
  ```

Now on inspecting the **Pardon Our Interruption** page you will find the `<body>` tag contains:

- The *class* attribute **`dist-GlobalHeader`**
- The *class* attribute **`dist-PageWrap`**

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with Selenium was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Distil detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Akamai Bot Manager detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)

Comment: nice root cause analysis. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Tried everything suggested here, nothing worked. Only this module worked for me:

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

I used it to get a website which had a bot detection. I tried to use all suggested methods in previous answers but without success. The use of this module is very straightforward and is described in the git repo itself.

Side note: moderators have deleted previous editions of this post several times, without a good reason IMHO. I hope this edit will get through. Good luck.