# Selenium just brings up a blank window (it doesn't load the webpage), how come?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Hi all i'm quite stuck,

My setup is:

- Selenium 3.141.0
- Firefox 63.0.3
- geckodriver 0.21.0 (have tried geckodriver 0.23.0 too)
- python 3.6.5
- Ubuntu 16.04

My Selenium scripts works great to all websites i wrote for, but 5 days ago i tried to scrape a specific website which came to my mind ([link](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/english/Pages/default.aspx)) and it fails loading the actual web page right after the driver initialization.

I constantly getting a blank page:
[image]

i made sure the web page exists and it loads flawlessly when i surf with my firefox browser.

Can somebody shed some sunlight on this mystery? i have no clue and dug into the geckodriver.log but haven't noticed the root cause for this issue.

Any suggestion how to investigate or resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have performed your *usecase* with the url `http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/english/Pages/default.aspx`.

It seems the the *website* is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *GeckoDriver* controled *Firefox* gets detected and subsequently gets **blocked**.

Here is the relevant `<tag>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/Nli.PL.HomePage/js/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Note**: Observe the presence of the keyword **dist** within the `link` tag.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Chrome browser initiated through ChromeDriver gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832413/chrome-browser-initiated-through-chromedriver-gets-detected)

Comment: Thank you! @DebanjanB
never heard about it, i'll dig into it.