# "HTTP ERROR 403" while executing script for clicking on search button which works fine with manual click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, http-status-code-403, http-error

I am trying to click on Search button after entering data in some fields which has to show the results(list of flight available from city A to city B on t he selected date) according to the search in the same page.

When I run the Selenium - Java script for this scenario system is showing **HTTP ERROR 403**, while it works fine when I do it manually.

Comment: Share your tried code , HTML code for the same. Anyway as of now I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Possible explanation is the web page recognizes that browser is controlled by selenium (3th patry in general) and filtering automatic requests. Or some authentification/authorization element is missing. Check both HTTP requests (manual vs selenium), you can use Chrome + Postman + Postman Interceptor to see headers, bodies, parameters, ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

### 403 Forbidden

The HTTP [**`403 Forbidden`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to [**`401`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

---

### Status

```
403 Forbidden
```

---

### Example response

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 
Date: Wed, 28 May 2019 07:28:00 GMT
```

---

### Reason

You code trials and the error trace log would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. Possibly the *WebDriver* controlled *Browser Client* is getting detected and hence the subsequent requests are getting **blocked**.

---

### Outro

You can find similar discussions in:

- [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests) and 404 (Not Found) with ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979980/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-429-too-many-req/55986553#55986553)
- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)