# Problem with 429 error while using googlesearch liblary in python

Tags: python, google-search, http-status-code-429

```
from googlesearch import search

query = input(": ")

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",):
    print(j)
```

Ok, so while running this code i get the 429 error even thought i use the user agent and i limit the num of results to 1.

I heve read the post about the 429 error and there was this one guy who did something with cookis but i'm not quite sure how to us it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758333/error-429-with-simple-query-on-google-with-requests-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 429 with simple query on google with requests python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758333/error-429-with-simple-query-on-google-with-requests-python)

Comment: Yea it kinda helped. I copy pasted the code from there and i no loger get the 429 error, but now my for loop doesnt print anything