# How to login into suntrust bank account using Selenium through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The goal is to login to a suntrust bank account and scrape information about checking account transaction data .

I have tried using request library and the selenium library . I am currently using selenium to see where the code fails .

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

LOGIN_URL = 'https://login.onlinebanking.suntrust.com/olb/login'
userID = 'username'
password = 'password'

chrome_path= "path_to_chromedriver"
chrome_options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.get_cookies()
driver.find_element_by_id('userId').send_keys(userID)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("suntrust-sign-on").click()
```

The program should successfully log the user in . However I receive an error message sayings **ReasonCode = 6004**.

Comment: please provide the full error message, your chrome version number, and keep in mind that requirement wont be  achievable without working credentials, username/pass

Comment: The code runs without error . The error comes from the suntrust website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit and tried to login as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://login.onlinebanking.suntrust.com/olb/login")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.suntrust-input-text.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched#userId"))).send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.suntrust-input-text.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid#password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.suntrust-sign-on.suntrust-button-text>span").click()
```

But was still unable to login.

Now on inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of **SUNTRUST - Online Banking Sign On** login page you will find the following tags within the `<body>` tag:

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/runtime.7d6aba6a1596ee0b757c.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/polyfills.65913a8531010587b6fe.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/scripts.46e57c2d57ad1b3d210d.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendor.43f2240dc35276d98b10.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main.5d227767baa37ef78819.js"></script>`

### Snapshot

[image: suntrust]

The presence of the phrase **dist** is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with **Selenium** was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Chrome browser initiated through ChromeDriver gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832413/chrome-browser-initiated-through-chromedriver-gets-detected/52833487#52833487)
- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)

Comment: is it possible to use proxy and then login may happen ? If yes and you know how to add that layer please share the solution. Thanks

Comment: @AmitJain Sounds like a possible alternative solution worth giving a try but I am sure it will tough call to bypass Distil.

Comment: Would using other methods such as Scrapy or Request library have the same result?

Comment: @JonathanCooper Honestly at this point of time I would avoid any comment using _Scrapy_ or _Request library_. Of coarse they are worth a try.

Comment: Related: this question and it's answers I found really interesting back when I first read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver